# representing large binary vector as problog fact/rule

Tags: prolog, probability, problog

In ProbLog, how do I represent the following as p-fact/rule :

A binary vector of size N, where P bits are 1 ? i.e. a bit is ON with probability P/N, where N > 1000

i come up with this, but it seem iffy :

```
 0.02::one(X) :- between(1,1000,X).
```

Want to use it later to make calculations on what happens if i apply two-or-more operations of bin-vec such as : AND,OR,XOR,count,overlap, hamming distance, but do it like Modeling rather than Simulation

F.e. if I ORed random 10 vec's, what is the probable overlap-count of this unionized vector and a new rand vec

... or what is the probability that they will overlap by X bits

.... questions like that

PS> I suspect cplint is the same.

---

Another try, but dont have idea how to query for 'single' result

```
1/10::one(X,Y) :- vec(X), between(1,10,Y). %vec: N=10, P=?
vec(X) :- between(1,2,X). %num of vecs
%P=2 ??
two(A,B,C,D) :- one(1,A), one(2,B), A =\= B, one(1,C), one(2,D), C =\= D.
```

---

based on @damianodamiono , so far :

```
P/N::vec(VID,P,N,_Bit).

prob_on([],[],_,_).
prob_on([H1|T1],[H2|T2],P,N):-
    vec(1,P,N,H1), vec(2,P,N,H2),
    prob_on(T1,T2,P,N).

query(prob_on([1],[1],2,10)).
query(prob_on([1,2,3,5],[1,6,9,2],2,10)).
```

Comment: should this be `prolog` tagged?

Comment: I could switch if needed to cplint

Answer (score 1):

I'm super happy to see that someone uses Probabilistic Logic Programming! Anyway, usually you do not need to create a list with 1000 elements and then attach 1000 probabilities. For example, if you want to state that each element of the list has a probabilty to be true of P/N (suppose 0.8), you can use (cplint and ProbLog have almost the same syntax, so you can run the programs on both of them):

```
0.8::on(_).
```

in the recursion.
For example:

```
8/10::on(_).

prob_on([]). prob_on([H|T]):-
    on(H),
    prob_on(T).
```

and then ask (in cplint)

```
?- prob(prob_on([1,2,3]),Prob).
Prob = Prob = 0.512
```

in ProbLog, you need to add `query(prob_on([1,2,3]))` in the program. Note the usage of the anonymous variable in the probabilistic fact `on/1` (is needed, the motivation may be complicated so I omit it). If you want a probability that depends on the lenght of the list and other variables, you can use flexible probabilities:

```
P/N::on(P,N).
```

and then call it in your predicate with

```
...
on(P,N),
...
```

where both `P` and `N` are ground when on/2 is called. In general, you can add also a body in the probabilistic fact (turning it into a clause), and perform whatever operation you want.

With two lists:

```
8/10::on_1(_).
7/10::on_2(_).

prob_on([],[]).
prob_on([H1|T1],[H2|T2]):-
    on_1(H1),
    on_2(H2),
    prob_on(T1,T2).

?- prob(prob_on([1,2,3,5],[1,6,9,2]),Prob).
Prob = 0.09834496
```

Hope this helps, let me know if something is still not clear.

Comment: thanks, i'm having hard time figuring how to represent P of N ON-bits, where the bits are not specified explicitly. if I query like prob_on([ _ , _ , _ , _ ], ...) it will generate gazillion results and takes alot of time ... i'm want just one result .. may be i trying the wrong thing !

Comment: Prob Logic seems easy on the surface but is very tricky ... it is fun ;)

Comment: I do not think I've fully understood your first comment. Can you provide an example? You should obtain only 1 result (the probability). Offtopic: are you doing a PhD in Italy?  Indeed ProbLog is very interesting and powerful

Comment: I want to represent ANY bin-vec not specific one.. f.e. any_vec(P,N) & any_vec(P,N) => res_vec(P1? , N), so i calculate P1 ... instead of vec([1,2,3]) & vec([6,9,2]) ... OT: not doing phd

Comment: The solution I wrote is not specific to the two verctors in the code, it can be applied to all vectors. What are P, P1, and N in your example?

Comment: P on bits, N vec size, P1 expected overlap